# Porter Stemmer Algorithm Not returning the expected output? when modified into def

Tags: python, algorithm, preprocessor, artificial-intelligence, normalization

I'm using the [`PorterStemmer`](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/) [Python Port](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/python.txt)

> The Porter stemming algorithm (or ‘Porter stemmer’) is a process for removing the commoner morphological and inflexional endings from words in English. Its main use is as part of a term normalisation process that is usually done when setting up Information Retrieval systems.

For the following..

> The other thing you need to do is reduce each word to its stem. For example, the words `sing`, `sings`, `singing`
>   all have the same stem, which is `sing`. There is a reasonably accepted way to do this, which is called Porter's
>   algorithm. You can download something that performs it from http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/.

And I've modified the code..

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PorterStemmer()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for f in sys.argv[1:]:
            infile = open(f, 'r')
            while 1:
                output = ''
                word = ''
                line = infile.readline()
                if line == '':
                    break
                for c in line:
                    if c.isalpha():
                        word += c.lower()
                    else:
                        if word:
                            output += p.stem(word, 0,len(word)-1)
                            word = ''
                        output += c.lower()
                print output,
            infile.close()
```

To read from an `input` and not a file from a preprocessed string and return the output.

```
def algorithm(input):
    p = PorterStemmer()
    while 1:
        output = ''
        word = ''
        if input == '':
            break
        for c in input:
            if c.isalpha():
                word += c.lower()
            else:
                if word:
                    output += p.stem(word, 0,len(word)-1)
                    word = ''
                output += c.lower()
        return output
```

Note if I position my `return output` onto the same indent as `while 1:` it turns into an `infinite loop`.

**Usage (Example)**

```
import PorterStemmer as ps
ps.algorithm("Michael is Singing");
```

**Output**

> Michael is

**Expected Output**

> Michael is Sing

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the culprit is that it doesn't currently write the final part of the input to `output` (try "Michael is Singing stuff", for example - it should write everything correctly and omit 'stuff'). There is likely a more elegant way to handle this, but one thing you could try is adding an `else` clause to the `for` loop. Since the issue is that the final word is not being included in `output`, we can use `else` to make sure that the final word gets added upon the completion of the `for` loop:

```
def algorithm(input):
    print input
    p = PorterStemmer()
    while 1:
        output = ''
        word = ''
        if input == '':
            break
        for c in input:
            if c.isalpha():
                word += c.lower()
            elif word:
                output += p.stem(word, 0,len(word)-1)
                word = ''
                output += c.lower()
        else:
            output += p.stem(word, 0, len(word)-1)  
        print output
        return output
```

This has been extensively tested with two test cases, so clearly it is bulletproof :) There are probably some edge cases crawling around there, but hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: @Killrawr no prob - happy it helps! Let me know if anything weird pops up and I'll see if I can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hmm I'm really sure what the problem is but some words aren't working like `purposes` becomes `purpos` and not `purpose`. If you're able to fix this I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, I was noticing the same thing, but I think it actually has to do with the port of the algorithm (the code is somewhat unclear in its naming conventions). You can try things like `dancing` as well, and the same thing happens. I say an issue with the port since I'm sure the actual algorithm has this handled properly (I also tested this against the raw code from the algorithm and the same thing happens). I'll see if I can find a quick fix.

Comment: I actually think we've just stumbled across a few of the known cases where the algorithm is incorrect. You can see the `Common Errors` section on http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/ for a more complicated explanation. In short, I think all stemmers will have some errors when trying to stem mechanically. Here is a thread that discusses building a list of known errors - maybe it can serve as a map of some sort? http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Good-list-of-English-words-that-get-quot-butchered-quot-by-Porter-Stemmer-td1010084.html

Comment: Was talking to another student and they said that, it doesn't really matter because its just making the words universal for stuff like wingrep. Thanks RocketDonkey

Comment: Sweet - glad you got it all sorted out. Good luck!